# Identification of a service

Tags: java

Service interface:

```
public interface UserInterface {

    void present();

    void onStart();

    void onStop();

}
```

I have two implementations: `TextUserInterface` and `GraphicalUserInterface`.
How can I identify the one I want to use when I launch my program? Source

```
private static void main(String[] args) {
    ServiceLoader<UserInterface> uiLoader = ServiceLoader.load(UserInterface.class);
    UserInterface ui = uiLoader.?   //what to do to identify the one I want to use?
}
```

I was thinking of introducing an `enum` with the type of UI, so I could just iterate through all services and pick the one I'd like to, but **isn't this approach just a misuse of services**? In this case when I want to pick `GraphicalUserInterface` I could just skip the `ServiceLoader` part and just instantiate one. The only difference I see is fact that without services, I'd have to `require` the `GraphicalUserInterface` module, which "kind of" **breaks the encapsulation.**

Comment: It depends on your need. If you as an administrator are going to decide the implementation, you can create some properties file which points to the right implementation, or you could have a factory or invoke the constructor directly. On the other hand, you could let the user decide. Then you would have to parse the input (args) and use some info there as a parameter gor the class that is responsible for instantiating the service.

Comment: Yes.  You don’t need ServiceLoader.  Just use `new` with one concrete implementation or the other.

Comment: @VGR Don't you think that `requires` instead of `uses` just breaks the encapsulation?

Comment: @Wiktor I’m not clear on whether the program is supposed to have both implementations bundled with it or not.  I assumed both were present at runtime, and a command line option would control which is instantiated.  So all use of the service provider mechanism would be irrelevant.

Comment: Most probably you just need a factory: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/factory_pattern.htm

Comment: @VGR Yes, both implementations will be present from the start. Additional fact, each implementation will come from separate module, so that's why I'm talking about encapsulation

Comment: If you are determined to use the service provider architecture, then what you suggested is the right way to do it:  add a method like `InterfaceType getType()` the service provider interface, where InterfaceType is an enum with constants representing CLI and GUI.  Then you can iterator (or stream) through the available service providers looking for one which is suitable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't actually think that it would be a misuse of it. As a matter of fact, what you get from `ServiceLoader.load(...)` method is an `Iteratable` object, and if you need for a specific service, you will have to iterate through all the available instances.
The idea of the enum is not that bad, but I suggest that you take advantage of the Java stream and filter for the instance you need. For example, you might have something like that:

```
enum UserInterfaceType {
    TEXT_UI, GRAPH_UI;
}

public interface UserInterface {
     UserInterfaceType getTypeUI();
     
     ...
}

// In your main method
ServiceLoader<UserInterface> uiLoader = ServiceLoader.load(UserInterface.class);
UserInterface ui = uiLoader.steam()
                           .filter(p -> p->getTypeUI() == <TypeUIyouNeed> )
                           .findFirst()
                           .get();
```

That is open to a number of possibilities, for example you can put this is a separated method, which receives in input a `UserInterfaceType` value, and it can retrieve the service implementation based on the type enum value you passed.

As I said, that is just the main idea, but definitely you are not doing any misuse of the `ServiceLoader`.

Comment: "As a matter of fact, what you get from ServiceLoader.load(...) method is an Iteratable object, and if you need for a specific service, you will have to iterate through all the available instances." - I think that's the right thinking